# The given term is not valid?

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-store, enterprise-keywords, keyword

I would like to know Why it is saying

> The given term is not valid.

I have added OD into term store. I would like to know what is the solution for this.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]